# /usr/bin/locale: source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: c++, macos, g++

using g++ to compile cpp file in macOS.

macOS v10.15.4

Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)

hello.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "hello word" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

in terminal I run:

```bash
g++ hello.cpp
```

[image: error]

Comment: Type `file hello.cpp` ... what does it say?

Comment: Somehow your compiler is finding the `locale` executable on your system and treating it as the `<locale>` header that `<iostream>` uses. Why? No idea.

Comment: What are the values of your `CPATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variables? (`echo $CPATH` etc.) Do they include `/usr/bin`?

Comment: hello.cpp: C++ source text, ASCII text @Eljay

Comment: yes no idea @chris

Comment: It is `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH ` error. It's done when i set  `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=":/usr/local/include"`.

Comment: ASCII text is valid UTF-8 text.  Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable has an incorrect value.

Simple fix:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=":/usr/local/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem happened for me on Catalina10.15.7 + gcc10.2 (homebrew), and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` method from Lin Weiye didn't work somehow.

Manually changing line 140 of `ostream` header from

```
include <locale>
```

to

```
include "locale"
```

did work. This will stop `ostream` from looking for locale executable via `PATH`, and force to look locale header in the same directory where `ofstream` header is.